# Android:PDF Editor library

Tags: android, pdf

Does anyone know any pdf editor or library (not in native C or C++) which can be integrated in our application or can give us the intent to use? Actually, I want to integrate pdfeditor with an esignature functionality in it. But I do not want to use native libraries like mupdf,vudroid etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please try follow library links.

- [Droid Reader](http://code.google.com/p/droidreader/)
- [APV PDF Viewer](http://code.google.com/p/apv/)

Comment: I have try Droid Reader but not run the application............ Please if any guys have any idea please reply .....

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have to do with native libraries at all, try [Qoppa qPDF Toolkit](http://www.qoppa.com/android/index.html) but it's not free!

Answer (score 0):

Qoppa's library is pretty good or can you hook into Reader?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [MuPDF](http://mupdf.com/). It's excellent. You might check the license if you are going for commercial products.